# Radio Button is selected by default in MVC for a Bool Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a Model as below

```
public partial class Approval
{
    public bool IsApproved { get; set; }
}
```

When rendering the Model in the View, I am usingRadio Button for IsApproved attribute

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, "Yes", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Approve"})
@Html.Label("Yes", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top" })
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, "No", htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Reject", })
@Html.Label("No", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top" })
```

When submitting, I am getting ModelState.IsValid false as the IsApproved is of type bool and i am passing string in View

If i change the Radio button like below

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, Model.IsApproved, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Approve"})
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, !Model.IsApproved, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "Reject", })
```

The Radio button gets checked by default on the page load which i do not want.

Suggest the correct approach

Comment: It's confusing that you have 2 controls for the same property. Surely `IsApproved` should be a `CheckBoxFor`

Comment: I understand that it should be a Dropdown, but the requirment is to have Radio Buttons

Comment: The values need to be "true" and "false", which bind to a `boolean` (not "yes" and "no"). If you don't want to have a button selected, you need to make you property `bool?` (nullable). And your 'labels' are not real labels (they have no relationship to the buttons - clicking on them does nothing)

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(Approval)
    {
        IsApproved = true;
    });
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Approval Approvalmodel)
{
    return Content("IsApproved: " + Approvalmodel.IsApproved);
}
```

View:

```
@model Approval

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, "true", new { id = "Approved" }) 
 @Html.Label("Yes", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top" })
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.IsApproved, "false", new { id = "Rejected" }) 
 @Html.Label("No", htmlAttributes: new { @style = "padding-right:10px;vertical-align:top" })
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```